# How do I plot field of view of an earth-based observatory in Galactic Coordinates?

Tags: coordinate, python, astropy

I would like to plot in Galactic Coordinate the sky field-of-view of an earth-based observatory (e.g. MAGIC). Something like this from [Liu et 2016](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/0004-637X/826/1/63/pdf).
[image]

I already know how plot source positions on a 2D projection of the sky (following this tutorial: http://learn.astropy.org/plot-catalog.html).
Is there a simple way to plot the field of view using astropy and/or astroplan and/or matplotlib?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Have you looked at Stellarium? It doesn't really answer your question but may give you a starting point